# Image not scaling

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm trying to scale a 3d cube with webGL.
I have defined all the parts needed to scale the imagine, but when I apply a slider to control the scaling, nothing happen.

However, if I set the scaling parameter in the .js file the image is scaled correctly, but I cannot control it with the slider.
This is my code:

- JS FILE -

  ```
  //matrix to do scaling 

  var scale_v = 1.0;

  var xformMatrix = new Float32Array([
  scale_v,   0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
  0.0,  scale_v,   0.0,  0.0,
  0.0,  0.0,  scale_v,   0.0,
  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0  ]);



  window.onload = function init() {
  //After loaded shaders and initialize attribute buffers

  [....]

   var u_xformMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_xformMatrix');
   gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_xformMatrix, false, xformMatrix);

   document.getElementById("radiusSlider").onchange = function(event) {
      scale_v=event.target.value;
   };
  ```
- HTML FILE -

  ```
  <div>
  Scaling -5<input id="scalingSlider" type="range"
  min="-5" max="5" step="0.5" value="1" />
  5
  </div>

  <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

  [....]
  uniform mat4 u_xformMatrix;

  void main()
  {
     fColor = vColor;
     gl_Position = 
     projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vPosition*u_xformMatrix;
  }
  </script>
  ```

Comment: Where is animation frame - does the update happens also there, or it's beeing drawn only once?

Comment: @Zydnar The animation frame is called inside this function: 

var render = function() {

    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    [...]

    
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix) );

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projectionMatrixLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix) );


    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices );

    requestAnimFrame(render);

}

Comment: changing variable scale_v does not change it inside xformMatrix - so instead create function setxformMatrix and there set xformMatrix. Because unless you're using observable changing variable does not change this new Float32Array - it's new object - so it's copy

Comment: Now I have defined this function:

        function setxformMatrix(scale_v){
            var xformMatrix = new Float32Array([
            scale_v,   0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
            0.0,  scale_v,   0.0,  0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  scale_v,   0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0  ]);
        }

And I call it when I update the value of the slider:

            document.getElementById("radiusSlider").onchange = function(event) {
            scale_v=event.target.value;
            setxformMatrix(scale_v)
            };

But still nothing happens...

Comment: You have to debug the code and see at what point something stays unchanged. I have no idea what is wrong yet.

Comment: Please most more code. You need to show how scale_v is used to generate a matrix, how that matrix is multiplied with other matrices, how the uniforms are updated with the resulting matrices. **Edit your question to include the code** do NOT just past stuff in comments please.